# Not well formed XML error on I-Phone

Tags: iphone, xml, xhtml, wap

I am working on a product which needs to display the site created on i-phone. However there is some content in the site which is causing the bad XML parsing error on I-Phone only. Is there any way to tell the I-Phone and other mobiles to ignore such type of errors .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am concerned there is no other way to parse a bad XML and tell iPhone that there is  a bad XML.Whenever you tried to parse the XML in iPhone , the didfailwththe error delegate method will be called.
Hope it helps you...........

Comment: Hi @Aman can you please explain me how to use this method in my JSP file. I am using the jsp for the wap site